# First word from the string

Tags: javascript, string

How can I get the first "word" out of these strings?

```
/User/Edit/
/Admin/Edit/2
/Tags/Add
```

I should get `User`, `Admin`, `Tags`, etc

http://jsfiddle.net/RV5r2/1/

Comment: in your fiddle you can get it `return ar[1];`

Answer (score 1):

as simple as this. since you split it up in an array, just return the first element:

```
  return ar[1];
```

and youre ready to go ;)

or you could reverse() first and the pop() :D but this migth be a  bit odd. just be sure you check if the array key [1] is set! by

```
return (typeof ar[1] !== 'undefined') ? ar[1] : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Or again:

```
return ar.slice(1,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you change a bit the logic in your lastWord method (**note**: lastWord is not a good name for this method - maybe firstWord?) to take in account paths/strings which don't start with "/" and paths that don't contain "/"

```
function lastWord(subject)
{
    var ar = subject.split("/");
    if(ar.length >= 2)
     {
         //we have at least one / in our string
        if(ar[0] !== "") {
            //the string doesn't start with /
           return ar[0];
        }
        else {
            //if the strings starts with / then the ar[0] will be ""
         return ar[1];
        }
    }
    else {
        //we return an empty string if the input was not valid, you could handle this differently
        return "";
    }        
}
```

This way :

- "/some/amazing/sentence" will return "some"
- "some/amazing/sentence" will return "some"
- "someamazingsentence" will return ""